# Select From Multiple tables Comma Separated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, join

What is best (low resources and speed)?

```
SELECT     C.[col1]
           , D.[col2] 
    FROM   tbl1 C,
           tbl2 D 
    WHERE  C.[colid] = D.[colid]
```

OR

```
SELECT  [tbl1].[col1], [tbl2].[col2]    
FROM    [tbl1] INNER JOIN [tbl2] ON
        [tbl1].[colid] = [tbl2].[colid]
```

Thank you!

UPDATE

Read [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Use a `Join` because it's more readable and more powerful. The performance is  the same since the optimizer will use the join anyway.

Comment: See also: [bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago)

Comment: Ok. Hilarious. I saw this code in some Microsoft Procedures, in ASP.NET Membership.

Comment: Related on DBA: [Is a join optimized to a where clause at runtime?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35596/is-a-join-optimized-to-a-where-clause-at-runtime). From the answer by Paul White: "The query optimizer almost always collapses the relational select into the join during optimization, meaning the two forms will very likely produce equivalent query plans, but there is no actual guarantee."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw this code in some recently Microsoft procedures (ASP.NET Membership).
As a bottom line, it is the same if you have INNER JOIN.

Thank you for your responses!